# drupal_http_request times out on Google Maps geocoding URL

Tags: google-maps, http-request

When I navigate to `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1200+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false` (the Google Maps Geocoding API test address) in my browser (Chrome), I get a json response as expected. However, when I `drupal_http_request()` the same url, I get a request timeout error. I tried setting the timeout to 60 instead of 30 but it doesn't help.

Why does `drupal_http_request('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1200+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false')` return a timeout error?

Comment: What do you get for `file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1200+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false')`? If that times out too the problem's probably environmental (network etc). It works fine from here using `drupal_http_request`

Comment: Interesting. `file_get_contents()` also timed out for me. But `drupal_http_request('http://drupal.stackexchange.com')` doesn't time out, it works fine.

Comment: Might be DNS, you could try using Google's (8.8.8.8), may help if your ISP is having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything mentioned, it sounds like a network issue; your web browser can reach the host @ **maps.google.com** but the server hosting Drupal can not. You can confirm this by trying to ping (`ping maps.google.com`) or telnet (`telnet maps.google.com 80`)  **maps.google.com** on your server console.

With either command, you should get some sort of timeout or unknown host errors if that's truly what the problem is. This could happen for various reasons: server host firewall rules, Google blocking your server IP (e.g. a shared hosting env where someone is hammering maps.google.com), DNS lookup problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly include url queries in the url when using drupal_http_request(). Use url().

```
$url = url('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json', ['query' => ['address'=>'1200 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA', 'sensor'=> FALSE]]);
drupal_http_request($url);
```